# How to count the number of comparisons and number of swaps in insertion and bubble sorts? (Swift)

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'm trying to create two functions for sorting arrays — first for bubble sort and second for insertion sort. Both of them should return not only the sorted array, but also the numbers of comparisons and swaps that happened during the sorting process. How do I do that?

Here is my current code:

```
func insertionSort(a: [Int]) -> (comparisonsCount: Int, swapsCount: Int, sortedArray: [Int]) {
    guard a.count > 1 else { return (0, 0, a) }

    var comparisons = 0
    var swaps = 0
    var b = a

    for i in 1..<b.count {
        var y = i

        while y > 0 && b[y] < b[y - 1] {
            b.swapAt(y - 1, y)
            y -= 1

        }
    }

    return (comparisons, swaps, b)
}
```

```
func bubbleSort(a: [Int]) -> (comparisonsCount: Int, swapsCount: Int, sortedArray: [Int]) {

    var b = a
    var comparisons = 0
    var swaps = 0

    for i in 0..<a.count-1 {
        for j in 0..<a.count-i-1 {

            if(b[j] > b[j+1]) {
                let temp = b[j]
                b[j] = b[j+1]
                b[j+1] = temp
                swaps += 1
            }

            comparisons += 1

        }
    }

    return (comparisons, swaps, b)

}
```

Comment: Your `bubbleSort` attempts to track the number of comparisons and swaps. What's the issue? Just do the same basic thing in your `insertionSort`.

Comment: My ```insertionSort``` function is written with while loop, and because of that I'm not sure how to implement tracking of that numbers.

Comment: How is a `while` loop any different (in this regard) than using `for`?

Comment: Even though I understand how this loop works, I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Should I use ```break``` and increase my counter by 1 when numbers should swap?

Comment: It's the same as your `bubbleSort`. Increment `swaps` where you swap and increment `comparisons` where you compare. No extra code such as `break` required.

Answer (score 0):

```
func insertionSort(a: [Int]) -> (comparisonsCount: Int, swapsCount: Int, sortedArray: [Int]) {
guard a.count > 1 else { return (0, 0, a) }

var comparisons = 0 
var swaps = 0
var b = a
for i in 1..<b.count {
    var y = i
    comaprisons += 2 // two comparison in while and it will happen at least once
    while y > 0 && b[y] < b[y - 1] {
        b.swapAt(y - 1, y)
        y -= 1
        swaps += 1
        comparisons += 2
    }

    if (y == 0){
       comparisons -= 1  // && Operator short circuiting explanation below
    }
}

 return (comparisons, swaps, b)
}
```

&& and || operators are both short circuiting operators. So if entered in the inner while loop y -= 1 can lead to y==0 . In which case b[y] < b[y - 1] this comparison won't happen. that's why comparison is reduced by 1

Comment: Your comparisons count adjustment is wrong. If on the second iteration of the loop, `y > 0` and `b[y] > b[y-1]`, which could happen, then you've made 4 comparisons. But your code will decrease the comparison count and say that you did it 3 times. You're probably better off here with `(1 + number of loop iterations)*2`. At most, you'll be off by one, which will be a very small percentage.